# Error C# Invoke SetPassword AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords, invoke

I'm trying to do a work for my final school project and I'm using C#, PHP, MySQL and Active Directory. The accounts will be created by the C# program into the Active Directory database, but I get this error while creating:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: O destino de uma invocação accionou uma excepção. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: O servidor de RPC não está disponível. (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
   --- Fim do rastreio da pilha de excepção interna ---
   em System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
   em PAP.ldap_functions.createUser(String domain, String first, String last, String description, String password, String[] groups, String username, String email, Int32 mobile, String streetAddress, String city, String postalcode, Boolean enabled) em C:\Users\Karbust\source\repos\PAP\PAP\ldap_functions.cs:line 176
```

I'm using this code to do it:

```
        public int createUser(String domain, String first, String last, String description, String password, String[] groups, String username, String email, Int32 mobile, String streetAddress, String city, String postalcode, bool enabled)
        {
            try
            {
                // create new user object and write into AD             
                DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(connectionstring_membros, adminlogin, adminpass);

                // User name (domain based)            
                DirectoryEntry objUser = user.Children.Add("CN=" + username, "user");

                // User name
                objUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Add(username + "@" + domain);

                // User name (older systems)           
                objUser.Properties["samaccountname"].Add(username);

                // Surname           
                objUser.Properties["sn"].Add(last);

                // Forename           
                objUser.Properties["givenname"].Add(first);

                // Display name           
                objUser.Properties["displayname"].Add(first + " " + last);

                // Description           
                objUser.Properties["description"].Add(description);

                // E-mail           
                objUser.Properties["mail"].Add(email);

                // Home dir (drive letter)           
                //objUser.Properties["homedirectory"].Add(homeDir);

                // Home dir (path)           
                //objUser.Properties["homedrive"].Add(homeDrive);

                objUser.CommitChanges();

                // set user's password             
                objUser.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
                //objUser.Properties["password"].Add(password);
                //objUser.SetPassword(password);
                //objUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });

                // Mobile Number
                objUser.Properties["mobile"].Add(mobile);

                // Telephone Number
                //objUser.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Add(telephoneNumber);

                // Street
                objUser.Properties["streetAddress"].Add(streetAddress);

                // City
                objUser.Properties["l"].Add(city);

                // State/Province
                //objUser.Properties["st"].Add(stateprovince);

                // Zip/Postal Code
                objUser.Properties["postalCode"].Add(postalcode);

                // enable account if requested (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144 for other codes)              
                if (enabled)
                    objUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "userAccountControl", "512" });

                // add user to specified groups             
                foreach (String thisGroup in groups)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry newGroup = objUser.Parent.Children.Find("CN=" + thisGroup, "group");

                    if (newGroup != null)
                        newGroup.Invoke("Add", new object[] { objUser.Path.ToString() });
                }

                objUser.CommitChanges();

                // make home folder on server                      
                //Directory.CreateDirectory(homeDir);

                // set permissions on folder, we loop this because if the program           
                // tries to set the permissions straight away an exception will be           
                // thrown as the brand new user does not seem to be available, it takes           
                // a second or so for it to appear and it can then be used in ACLs           
                // and set as the owner             
                /*bool folderCreated = false;

                while (!folderCreated)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // get current ACL                   
                        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(homeDir);
                        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

                        // Add full control for the user and set owner to them                   
                        IdentityReference newUser = new NTAccount(domain + @"\" + username);
                        dSecurity.SetOwner(newUser);
                        FileSystemAccessRule permissions = new FileSystemAccessRule(newUser, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
                        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(permissions);

                        // Set the new access settings.                   
                        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
                        folderCreated = true;
                    }
                    catch (System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException)
                    {
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // other exception caught so not problem with user delay as                  
                        // commented above                   
                        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:" + ex.ToString());
                        return 0;
                    }
                }*/

                return 1;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception caught: " + ex.ToString(), "Criar Cliente");

                fncs.ErroToTxt(ex);

                return 0;
            }
        }
```

The account is created but everything after

```
objUser.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
```

is not working, the program gives the exception is this line.

I'm using a code I found on the internet that is working 100% and adapted to my needs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace activeDirectoryLdapExamples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // connect to LDAP             
            //DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();

            // define vars for user             
            String domain = "vm.pap";
            String first = "First name";
            String last = "Last name";
            String description = ".NET Test";
            String password = "xpto001!";
            String[] groups = { "gr_membros" };
            //String username = first.ToLower() + last.Substring(0, 1).ToLower();
            String username = "charparodar";
            String email = "email@mail.com";
            String homeDrive = "H:";
            String homeDir = @"\\vm.pap\data3\USERS\" + username;

            // create user            
            try
            {
                if (createUser(domain, first, last, description, password, groups, username, email, homeDrive, homeDir, true) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Account created!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Problem creating account :(");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        static int createUser(String domain, String first, String last, String description, String password, String[] groups, String username, String email, String homeDrive, String homeDir, bool enabled)
        {
            // create new user object and write into AD             
            //DirectoryEntry user = myLdapConnection.Children.Add("OU=" + first + ",OU= " + last, "user");
            //DirectoryEntry user = myLdapConnection.Children.Add("CN=" + first + " " + last, "user");
            DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://vmpap/OU=Membros,OU=Utilizadores,DC=vm,DC=pap", "Administrator", "xpto001!");

            // User name (domain based)            
            //user.Properties["userprincipalname"].Add(username + "@" + domain);
            //user.Invoke("Add", new object[] { username + "@" + domain });
            //user.Invoke("Add", new object[] { "ansilva15ig@vm.pap" });
            DirectoryEntry objUser = user.Children.Add("CN=ansilva15ig","user");

            // User name
            objUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Add(username + "@" + domain);

            // User name (older systems)           
            objUser.Properties["samaccountname"].Add(username);

            // Surname           
            objUser.Properties["sn"].Add(last);

            // Forename           
            objUser.Properties["givenname"].Add(first);

            // Display name           
            objUser.Properties["displayname"].Add(first + " " + last);

            // Description           
            objUser.Properties["description"].Add(description);

            // E-mail           
            objUser.Properties["mail"].Add(email);

            // Home dir (drive letter)           
            //objUser.Properties["homedirectory"].Add(homeDir);

            // Home dir (path)           
            //objUser.Properties["homedrive"].Add(homeDrive);

            objUser.CommitChanges();

            // set user's password             
            objUser.Invoke("SetPassword", password);

            // enable account if requested (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144 for other codes)              
            if (enabled)
                objUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "userAccountControl", "512" });

            // add user to specified groups             
            foreach (String thisGroup in groups)
            {
                DirectoryEntry newGroup = objUser.Parent.Children.Find("CN=" + thisGroup, "group");

                if (newGroup != null)
                    newGroup.Invoke("Add", new object[] { objUser.Path.ToString() });
            }

            objUser.CommitChanges();

            // make home folder on server                      
            //Directory.CreateDirectory(homeDir);

            // set permissions on folder, we loop this because if the program           
            // tries to set the permissions straight away an exception will be           
            // thrown as the brand new user does not seem to be available, it takes           
            // a second or so for it to appear and it can then be used in ACLs           
            // and set as the owner             
            /*bool folderCreated = false;

            while (!folderCreated)
            {
                try
                {
                    // get current ACL                   
                    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(homeDir);
                    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

                    // Add full control for the user and set owner to them                   
                    IdentityReference newUser = new NTAccount(domain + @"\" + username);
                    dSecurity.SetOwner(newUser);
                    FileSystemAccessRule permissions = new FileSystemAccessRule(newUser, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
                    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(permissions);

                    // Set the new access settings.                   
                    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
                    folderCreated = true;
                }
                catch (System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException)
                {
                    Console.Write(".");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // other exception caught so not problem with user delay as                  
                    // commented above                   
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:" + ex.ToString());
                    return 1;
                }
            }*/
            return 0;
        }
        static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
        {
            // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings             
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("vm.pap");
            ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://192.168.1.80/OU=Utilizadores,DC=vm,DC=pap";
            ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
            return ldapConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone that tries to help

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my end and affirm that your code works absolutely fine. So, there is nothing wrong with the code.

I was reading [something](http://www.open-a-socket.com/index.php/2017/08/03/how-to-resolve-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-when-enabling-seamless-single-sign-on/) and so as a solution, I would request you to temporarily disable the Firewall on PC where you are testing the software or application. Then test.

If it's a software application, test by running the software as ***Run as Administrator***

Comment: Nothing changed (firewall disabled and running as admin)

On both codes I'm using exactly the same machine running on VMWare Workstation on the computer I'm coding the software, the only difference is that on the code that is working I only used an console application and now I'm creating an Windows Form...

Thanks anyway

Comment: I was able to solve it. The domain has some misconfiguration, but I already tried to solve it by repeating everything, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

So, I edited the hosts file and pointed the domain, in this case "vm.pap" to the machine's ip (192.168.1.80), with this I was able set the program to work.